# What are the differences between QtQml and QtQuick?

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-qmlmodule.html

QtQml and QtQuick seem to be different things that's why there are two separate import statements.

`import QtQml 2.2`
`import QtQuick 2.3`

***What are the differences between QtQml and QtQuick, and in which real life cases should each of them be used?***

Comment: QML positioned as alternative to QtScripting.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19696153/difference-between-qt-qml-and-qt-quick

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-index.html)

> Note that while the Qt QML module provides the language and
>   infrastructure for QML applications, the Qt Quick module provides many
>   visual components, model-view support, an animation framework, and
>   much more for building user interfaces.

So QtQML provides basic infrastructure, while QtQuick provides UI Components.

Also found this from docs.

> Most clients will never need to use the QtQml import, as all of the
>   types are also provided by the QtQuick namespace which may be imported
>   as follows: